# Selecting Features within distance and direction using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

Is there a way to select features in a layer by location based on their proximity to another feature and the direction? E.G., select all features within 10 meters north of current selection?

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1

I am selecting points, and I have scripting abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define "north of" as being simply that a newly selected point has a Y coordinate greater than any of the originally selected features, then this should be doable by:

1. using Select By Location within a distance of 10 meters to get them first
2. then use ArcPy to work out the Y coordinate of the northernmost point
3. then use ArcPy to examine the Y coordinate of each of the newly selected points to determine whether they need to be selected.

If your algorithm is more complicated than that then I think it would be best illustrated with a picture.